# Swift 3 UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> migration

Tags: swift, unsafemutablepointer

Trying to migrate my code to Swift 3 but I can't seem to solve this problem. Need some help!

I've got this audio buffer and a pointer to it's channel data... like this

```
var buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer  
var bufPtrs = [UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>]()  
for index in 0..<outputChannelCount {  
     let channelPtr = buffer.floatChannelData?[index]  
      bufPtrs.append(channelPtr!)  
}
```

Now I need to hand in this pointer to a C library function that does some resampling.

This function wants an UInt8 pointer to an array of UInt8 elements, like this...

```
func swr_convert(_ s: OpaquePointer!,
 _ out: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?>!,
 _ out_count: Int32,
 _ in: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<UInt8>?>!,
 _ in_count: Int32) -> Int32
```

Before Swift 3 I just used this code successfully.

```
numSamplesDecoded = swr_convert(audioPlayer.swrContext!,  
                        UnsafeMutablePointer(bufPtrs),  
                        frame.memory.nb_samples,  
                        UnsafeMutablePointer(frame.memory.extended_data),  
                        frame.memory.nb_samples)
```

But that doesn't work in Swift 3.

How do I reference this chunk of memory in Swift 3 so that the C library function will accept it?

I really don't understand the explanation in the documentation for Swift 3.

Please help / Jörgen

Comment: Can you be more precise what "doesn't work in Swift 3" means? Doesn't it compile? Doesn't it crash when run? Does it run but produce the wrong result?